# How can I correct for residual autocorrelation in a fixed effect panel model?

Tags: panel-data, residuals, fixed-effects-model, autoregressive

The residuals have an AR(2) structure. Is it appropriate to add AR terms to a fixed-effects panel model?

Comment: Can you add some more details to your question? How many timepoints do you have in your panel? Often you can tell your software that your data have this structure & it can take care of it for you w/o your having to explicitly add terms to the model.

Comment: The data is for 99 cities over a period of 22 months. I am using the plm package in R. The structure of the residuals is a prototype Ar(1) (possibly an AR(2)).

Comment: Do you have 22 monthly measurements per city? How do you know it's AR(1), from exploring these data or from some prior research?

Comment: Yes, there are 22 monthly measurements per city. I know it is an AR(1) because I plotted the ACF and PACF of the residuals, and the pattern indicated that an AR(1) structure was present.